# NSString is getting extra characters added to it when using fileURLWithPath

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

When I type the line directly like this:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Brandon/Desktop/challenge.txt"];
```

I get this output when I display what's in the object using NSLog:

> fileURL: file://localhost/Users/Brandon/Desktop/challenge.txt

And all is well.

But I want to pass a variable so the user can enter their own string. When I do that, like so:

```
NSString *strURL = @"/Users/Brandon/Desktop/challenge.txt";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strURL];
```

I get this and the program crashes:

> fileURL: file://localhost/Users/Brandon/Desktop/challenge.txt%0A

Why?

Comment: We really need to see more of your real code to understand what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

`%0A` is a [URL encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) line feed, probably deriving by a newline in the user input.

The solution is to sanitize the input, but I cannot be more specific unless you post the code you use to retrieve the string from the user.

Comment: Sorry I keep hitting enter for newline and it posts... gotta get used to that.  The input from the user has nothing to do with it: Here is the output of strURL right before the string gets passed into fileURL: strURL: /Users/Brandon/Desktop/challenge.txt

Comment: I've looked at converting the NSString to a path object somehow... I'll try NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString: strURL];

Comment: The big question is: where does the `NSString` come from? You said ` the user can enter their own string` but you are not showing anything like that. One thing is for sure: you have an extra line feed in your input.

Comment: You're not getting it. The line feed is not present in the NSString variable strURL immediately before strURL is passed into: NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strURL];  I know it's not present in the string because I output the string object using NSLog twice, once before as strURL and once after when the path has been passed into the fileURL variable.  Only in the fileURL variable does it have %0A

Comment: Is it your *actual* code? Copy-pasted here? Or did you omit anything?

Comment: That's the actual code. You can see the output using NSLog from the NSString strURL in my first post.  The line below it shows it being entered using NSURL fileURLWithPath to fileURL and being output again using nslog